# Why are my long exposures with a certain lens not crisp even though I'm using a tripod?

Tags: tripod, blur, camera-shake

I am new to DSLR photography, and using using  a Canon 1300D and Tamron 18-200. While using 200mm and trying to take a picture at 5 second or longer shutter speeds, I am developing camera shake and the McLean pictures ... even though I am using a tripod.

With the same settings while I use the 55-250 canon lens, I am getting crisp pictures. Is my Tamron lens faulty? Under 5sec shutter speed I am getting crisp images.

Comment: What are "McLean pictures"? Is that an autocorrect mistake perhaps?

Comment: Have you tried turning off image stabilization? Image stabilization on some lenses don't work well with tripods.

Comment: Please include some sample pictures in your question, along with shutter speed, aperture and ISO for each.

Comment: Often, when we jab the shutter button with our finger, it can shake the tripod. If the situation allows it, using the self timer with 2 to 5 seconds delay can let that shake settle down first.

Comment: @scottbb McLean pictures is what you get when your tripod has a broken leg.

Comment: Just to eliminate the obvious: Are the images you take with the Tamron 18-200mm lens any better when you use much shorter shutter times? How do they look in brighter light at 1/1000 second?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent blurred images when using a tripod?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/22125/how-can-i-prevent-blurred-images-when-using-a-tripod)

Answer (score 3):

Sample images would be awesome - as there's a few questions here that might help you:

[Why are my photos not crisp](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/50006/why-are-my-photos-not-crisp/50022#50022)

[How can I prevent blurred images when using a tripod?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/22125/how-can-i-prevent-blurred-images-when-using-a-tripod?rq=1)

[How to stabilize a tripod](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/94720/how-to-stabilize-a-tripod)

My own hunch is what WayneF commented: you're probably getting a bit of wobble from pressing the shutter release button. If this is actually the case, you've got options!

- Look into a remote shutter release
- Use your cameras timer mode - if there is a short and a long timer, the short should be sufficient
- Use mirror lock-up with either of the two methods above. The first shutter release will trigger the mirror to lock up. The second will trip the exposure. This allows you to add some time in between the mirror slapping and the exposure, further reducing any possible movement.

This answer, however, is *highly* speculative - and I'd really like to update it with something more relevant to you. So, please edit your question and add some samples to it! Thanks!

Comment: Second the remote shutter release - a $20 tripod with a remote release will trump a $200 tripod without.

Answer (score 3):

Although you do not state whether you are using optical image stabilization, I suspect **optical image stabilization is responding to phantom movements** because you have problems with exposures > 5 sec, but *not* with exposures < 5 sec. (You state: "Under 5sec shutter speed I am getting crisp images.") If this is the case, **turn off image stabilization while using a tripod.**

Image stabilization is the only lens function that actively alters the image during exposure. Aperture and focus remain constant during exposure. Although zoom is not intended to change during exposure, **zoom creep is possible.**

Other possibilities include:

- Slipping of tripod components.
- Spurious movements of the tripod. Use a sturdier tripod or hang sandbags.
- Movement of the camera caused by pressing the shutter button or mirror slap. However, this is unlikely in your situation because such movements would not take > 5 sec to affect the image. They would also be expected to affect images taken with both of your lenses.

See also (the same links [Hueco lists](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/102132/75526)):

- [How can I prevent blurred images when using a tripod?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/22125/75526)
- [How to stabilize a tripod?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/94720/75526)
- [Why are my photos not crisp?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/50006/75526)